# jquery в зависимости от ссылки подставлять значение в Input

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Нужна помощь. Моих знаний не хватает.

Делаю  [лендинг](http://uclend.kkulakov.ru/). Необходимо в [разделе](http://uclend.kkulakov.ru/#price) "Выберите вашу подпись" при нажатии на кнопку "ЗАКАЗАТЬ", должно выводиться модальное окно с формой обратной связи, в котором поле "Вы выбрали подпись:" должно автоматически подставлять название той подписи на кнопку которой нажали.

Триггер запуска кнопки:

```
<div class="btnfull btnfull-o #wrapper">
    <p><a class="modalbox" href="#inline">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a></p>
</div>
```

Код формы:

```
<div id="inline" class="form-container-pop">
   <legend>
      <h2>Подача заявки</h2>
   </legend>
   <form action="#" method="post" id="contact" >
      <div class="input-prepend">
         <input class="form-field input-medium focused txt" value="" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя"/>
         <div class="error-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-prepend">
         <input class="form-field input-medium focused txt" value="" id="phon" type="text" placeholder="Введите номер телефона"/>
         <div class="error-box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-prepend">
         <label for="sign">Вами выбрана подпись:</label>
         <input class="form-field input-medium focused" value="Для идентификации личности" id="sign" type="text" placeholder="Для идентификации личности" readonly />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="submit-button feedback" name="send" id="send" value="Заказать">
   </form>
</div>
```

Код js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".modalbox").fancybox();



   $('input#name, input#phon').unbind().blur(function() {

       // Для удобства записываем обращения к атрибуту и значению каждого поля в переменные
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var val = $(this).val();

       // После того, как поле потеряло фокус, перебираем значения id, совпадающие с id данного поля
       switch (id) {
           // Проверка поля "Имя"
           case 'name':
               var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

               // Eсли длина имени больше 2 символов, оно не пустое и удовлетворяет рег. выражению,
               // то добавляем этому полю класс .not_error,
               // и ниже в контейнер для ошибок выводим слово " Принято", т.е. валидация для этого поля пройдена успешно

               if (val.length > 3 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val)) {
                   $(this).addClass('not_error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                       .css('color', 'green')
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '10px'
                       }, 400)
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '5px'
                       }, 400);
               }

               // Иначе, мы удаляем класс not-error и заменяем его на класс error, говоря о том что поле содержит ошибку валидации,
               // и ниже в наш контейнер выводим сообщение об ошибке и параметры для верной валидации
               else {
                   $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Имя" обязательно для заполнения<br>, длина имени должна составлять не менее 2 символов<br>, поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы')
                       .css('color', 'red')
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '10px'
                       }, 400)
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '5px'
                       }, 400);
               }
               break;

               // Проверка телефона
           case 'phon':
               var rv_phon = /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/;
               if (val != '' && rv_phon.test(val)) {
                   $(this).addClass('not_error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                       .css('color', 'green')
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '10px'
                       }, 400)
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '5px'
                       }, 400);
               } else {
                   $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                   $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Телефон" обязательно для заполнения<br>, поле должно содержать правильный email-адрес<br>')
                       .css('color', 'red')
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '10px'
                       }, 400)
                       .animate({
                           'paddingLeft': '5px'
                       }, 400);
               }
               break;



       } // end switch(...)

   }); // end blur()


   // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
   $('form#contact').submit(function(e) {

       // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
       e.preventDefault();

       // После того, как мы нажали кнопку "Отправить", делаем проверку,
       // если кол-во полей с классом .not_error равно 3 (так как у нас всего 3 поля), то есть все поля заполнены верно,
       // выполняем наш Ajax сценарий и отправляем письмо адресату

       if ($('.not_error').length == 2) {
           // Eще одним моментом является то, что в качестве указания данных для передачи обработчику send.php, мы обращаемся $(this) к нашей форме,
           // и вызываем метод .serialize().
           // Это очень удобно, т.к. он сразу возвращает сгенерированную строку с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы.

           $.ajax({
               url: 'sendmessage.php',
               type: 'post',
               data: $(this).serialize(),

               beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                   $('form#contact :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               },

               success: function(response) {
                   $('form#contact :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                   $('form#contact :text').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
                   alert(response);
                   $('form#contact').fadeOut("fast", function() {
                       $(this).before("<p><strong>Ваше сообщение отправлено!</strong></p>");
                       setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1500);

                   });

               }
           });
       }

       // Иначе, если количество полей с данным классом не равно значению 3, мы возвращаем false,
       // останавливая отправку сообщения в невалидной форме
       else {
           return false;
       }

   }); // end submit()

}); // end script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
$(".modalbox").fancybox();
```

дописать что-то типа такого:

```
$(".modalbox").on('click', function(){
  var i = $(this).prop('rel');
  $('[name="sign"]').prop('checked', false);
  $('[name="sign"]').eq(i).prop('checked', true);
});
```

и к каждой ссылке добавить атрибут:

```
<a class="modalbox" href="#inline" rel="0">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
<a class="modalbox" href="#inline" rel="1">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
<a class="modalbox" href="#inline" rel="2">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
```

и удалить дубли ID

Comment: Огонь! :-) Спасибо большое, выручили!