# jquery форма обратной связи не пересылает данные

Tags: jquery

Форма обратной не передает введенные данные в форму, ни как не могу понять в чем дело. Помогите.

Есть [лендинг](http://uclend.kkulakov.ru/#price). В разделе *Выберите вашу подпись* есть кнопка `ЗАКАЗАТЬ` (самая последняя пока выдает форму).

От сюда взял [пример](http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/134) формы.

**Код формы:**

```
<div id="inline" class="form-container-pop">
    <legend><h2>Подача заявки</h2></legend>
    <div align="center" id='loadBar'></div>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="contact" >

       <div class="input-prepend">
           <input class="form-field input-medium focused txt" value="" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя"/>
           <div class="error-box"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="input-prepend">
           <input class="form-field input-medium focused txt" value="" id="phon" type="text" placeholder="Введите номер телефона"/>
           <div class="error-box"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="input-prepend">
        <label for="sign">Вами выбрана подпись:</label>
        <input class="form-field input-medium focused" value="Для идентификации личности" id="sign" type="text" placeholder="Для идентификации личности" readonly />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="submit-button feedback" name="send" id="send" value="Получить консультацию">
</form>
</div>
```

**Код js:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox();
    $('input#name, input#phon').unbind().blur( function(){

        // Для удобства записываем обращения к атрибуту и значению каждого поля в переменные
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();

       // После того, как поле потеряло фокус, перебираем значения id, совпадающие с id данного поля
       switch(id)
       {
             // Проверка поля "Имя"
             case 'name':
                var rv_name = /[^(\w)|(\x7F-\xFF)|(\s)]/; // используем регулярное выражение

                // Eсли длина имени больше 2 символов, оно не пустое и удовлетворяет рег. выражению,
                // то добавляем этому полю класс .not_error,
                // и ниже в контейнер для ошибок выводим слово " Принято", т.е. валидация для этого поля пройдена успешно

                if(val.length > 3 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val))
                {
                 $(this).addClass('not_error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
                 .css('color','green')
                 .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                 .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
             }

              // Иначе, мы удаляем класс not-error и заменяем его на класс error, говоря о том что поле содержит ошибку валидации,
              // и ниже в наш контейнер выводим сообщение об ошибке и параметры для верной валидации

              else
              {
                 $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
                 $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Имя" обязательно для заполнения<br>, длина имени должна составлять не менее 3 символов<br>, поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы')
                 .css('color','red')
                 .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
                 .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
             }
             break;

           // Проверка телефона
           case 'phon':
           var rv_phon = /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/;
           if(val != '' && rv_phon.test(val))
           {
              $(this).addClass('not_error');
              $(this).next('.error-box').text('Принято')
              .css('color','green')
              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
          }
          else
          {
              $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error');
              $(this).next('.error-box').html('поле "Телефон" обязательно для заполнения<br>, поле должно содержать правильный номер телефона<br>')
              .css('color','red')
              .animate({'paddingLeft':'10px'},400)
              .animate({'paddingLeft':'5px'},400);
          }
          break;



       } // end switch(...)

     }); // end blur()


            // Теперь отправим наше письмо с помощью AJAX
            $('form#contact').submit(function(e){

         // Запрещаем стандартное поведение для кнопки submit
         e.preventDefault();

         // После того, как мы нажали кнопку "Отправить", делаем проверку,
         // если кол-во полей с классом .not_error равно 3 (так как у нас всего 3 поля), то есть все поля заполнены верно,
         // выполняем наш Ajax сценарий и отправляем письмо адресату

         if($('.not_error').length == 2)
         {
            // Eще одним моментом является то, что в качестве указания данных для передачи обработчику send.php, мы обращаемся $(this) к нашей форме,
            // и вызываем метод .serialize().
            // Это очень удобно, т.к. он сразу возвращает сгенерированную строку с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы.

            $.ajax({
                url: 'sendmessage.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){
                   $('form#contact :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
               },

               success: function(response){
                $('form#contact :input').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('form#contact :text').val('').removeClass().next('.error-box').text('');
                alert(response);
                $('form#contact').fadeOut("fast", function(){
                    $(this).before("<p><strong>Ваше сообщение отправлено!</strong></p>");
                    setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1500);

                });

            }
        });
        }

        // Иначе, если количество полей с данным классом не равно значению 3, мы возвращаем false,
        // останавливая отправку сообщения в невалидной форме
        else
        {
          return false;
      }

    }); // end submit()

}); // end script
```

**Код php Обработчика:**

```
$sendto   = "admin@uclend.com";
$usermail = "info@uclend.ru";
$content  = $_POST['phon'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$sign  = $_POST['sign'];
// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Заявка на электронную подпись";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>\r\n";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Навая заявка</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Заявка:</strong> $content </p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Поизучав материалы в инете. Как я понял, метод `$(this).serialize()` должен формировать строку из данных формы, из которой потом php обработчик через переменные `$name = $_POST['name'];` должен забирать данные и включать их в письмо.
Но письмо приходит без этих данных.

Comment: с JS все номрмально, что-то не так на сервере, т.е. в описанном вами сценарии я, как и ожидается, получаю переменные в $_POST. Покажите весь код серверной части.

Comment: @k.. А что именно показать? Код Index.html? Или кучу js файлов? Так как я не спец в php и js, я использовал несколько разных js сценариев для разных форм на лендинге(так как не знаю как это реализовать с помощью одного), могло ли это-как то повлиять?

Comment: **Код php Обработчика**, раньше не видно было как оно присваивается, теперь - видно, должно работать.

Comment: Попробовал сейчас запрос отослать. uclend.kkulakov.ru Все так же приходят пустые сообщения. Вся обвязка в сообщении приходит, само же значение пустое. У меня формы обратной связи в шапке и в разделе контакты реализованы одним скриптом и своим php обработчиком, а всплывающая форма другим и своим обработчиком. Могут они как-то пересекаться?

Comment: И еще вот такую ошибку пишет обработчик в логах сервера: [06-Nov-2015 16:07:31 Europe/Moscow] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Я вообще не заморачивался - сделал форму через https://formfor.site, работает отлично. Сообщения уходят в telegram и почту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у INPUT'ов нет атрибутов NAME, вот и не работает

Comment: Блин, действительно. Заработала!!! :-) Вот спасибо! Можете еще момент подсказать? Как сделать так, чтоб в зависимости от нажатия на одну из 3х кнопок "ЗАКАЗАТЬ" в запустившейся форме автоматически выбирался вид электронной подписи. Вот тема:

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464145/jquery-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-input